# Spark unable to decode Avro when partitioned?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro

I am running into a problem decoding Avro data with Spark. The schema and encoded data are valid -- I'm able to decode the data with the avro-tools CLI utility. I'm also able to decode the data with Hive and other tools as well... except Spark.

For a simple example, I took the example schema and data found in the Oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26161_02/html/GettingStartedGuide/jsonbinding-overview.html#avro-json-binding-with-record):

**Schema**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MemberInfo",
  "namespace": "avro",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "FullName",
      "fields": [
        {"name": "first", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "last", "type": "string"}
      ]
    }},
    {"name": "age", "type": "int"},
    {"name": "address", "type": {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "Address",
      "fields": [
        {"name": "street", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "city", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "state", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "zip", "type": "int"}
      ]
    }}
  ]
}
```

**Data**

```
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Percival",
    "last":  "Lowell"
  },
  "age": 156,
  "address": {
    "street": "Mars Hill Rd",
    "city": "Flagstaff",
    "state": "AZ",
    "zip": 86001
  }
}
```

**Create (no partitions - works)**

If I create with no partitions, I'm able to query the data just fine.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/path/to/data/dir'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/path/to/schema.avsc');
```

**Create (partitions -- does NOT work)**

If I create with no partitions, and then manually add a partition, all of my queries return an error. (I need to manually add partitions because I cannot control the structure of the data directories, so dynamic partitioning is not an option.)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo
PARTITIONED BY (ds STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/path/to/schema.avsc');

ALTER TABLE foo ADD PARTITION (ds='1') LOCATION '/path/to/data/dir';
```

The error:

```
spark-sql> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ds = '1';

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.stringResult(HiveContext.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLDriver.run(SparkSQLDriver.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.processCmd(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver$.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found avro.FullName, expecting union
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:292)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:155)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroDeserializer$SchemaReEncoder.reencode(AvroDeserializer.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroDeserializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe.deserialize(AvroSerDe.java:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$$anonfun$fillObject$2.apply(TableReader.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```